# I cannot get git to unignore a subdirectory, even after excluding it in gitignore

Tags: git

In my .gitignore file, I was ignoring a directory like this:

`var`

Then I realized I want to track `var/package` and all its contents. So, I've added that exclusion to gitignore. I've tried many combinations, but have settled on the following for what seems to be logical, [especially from other discussions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder).

```
!var/
var/*
!var/package
!var/package/
!var/package/*
```

But whenever new files are written to `var/package`, they are not detected. They *are* added if I --force them specifically, but not through usual procedures such as `git add .`

Is there a command I need to be issuing to reset .gitignore to now finally pick up the new gitignore instructions? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove anything about var from .gitignore. Create a var/.gitignore with the contents:

```
/*
!/package
```

You will obviously need to `git add -f var/.gitignore` but after that all should be well.

another option is, in your top level .gitignore, say:

```
/var/*
!/var/package
```

If either do not work, please type `find . -name .gitignore | xargs egrep .` and `cat .git/info/exclude` and let us know what it returns.

Comment: Thanks, Seth! Neither of those originally worked, which led me to your troubleshooting "find" step, which made me realize the problem. I was using a catchall .gitignore from GitHub and something in there caused this. I removed all the stuff except for my own ignores and then both methods you mentioned worked.

Comment: @Seth what's the difference between with and without the `/` before the `var`

Comment: @toolchainX: Leading / means that the path is rooted at the current directory.  "/var" means ignore the file/directory in the current currently named "var".  "var" means ignore any file/directory named "var" in this directory or any child directory.  And to be complete "var/" means ignore any directory named "var" in this or any child directory.  "/var/" does what you might hopefully suspect.